# iterating through character array to find occurance of each letter in the alphabet

Tags: c, arrays, string, unix

it will go fine up to a certain point, like A-G will count fine. but it'll hit a letter like I or H and throw up some crazy number like 1.7 billion occurrences and then try to print out that many asterisks in the diagram. I've been banging my head against this and can't figure it out.. what is wrong with this for loop? the for loop in question is in Step 2

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXROWS 100
#define NUM_ALPHABETS 26

int main(){

        int count, i, j, k;

        char sentence[MAXROWS];
        char alphabets[] = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', '$
        int frequency[NUM_ALPHABETS];


// step 1:Write a function that reads a sentence from the keyboard (2 pts)
        printf("Please enter a sentence: \n");
        fgets(sentence, sizeof(sentence), stdin);

// step 2:Find out the frequency of the alphabets  in the sentence, ignore uppercase or lowercase in the sentence(4 pts)

        for(i = 0; sentence[i] != "\n"; i++) {
                for(j = 0; j < NUM_ALPHABETS; j++) {
                        if(tolower(sentence[i]) == tolower(alphabets[j])) {
                                frequency[j]++;
                        }
                }
        }


// step 3: Print the histogram as shown in the screenshot(4 pts)

        printf("%12s%12s%10s\n", "Alphabets", "Frequency", "Histogram");
        for(j = 0; j < NUM_ALPHABETS; j++) {
                printf("%12c%12d     ", alphabets[j], frequency[j]);
                for(k = 0; k < frequency[j]; k++) {
                        printf("*");
                }
                printf("\n");
        }

        return 0;
}
```

it should print out a diagram, and it does up to a certain point. but once it hits some random letter (it's not the same letter every time) it'll count around a billion or 2 billion occurances( sometimes it's even negative)

Comment: you don't initialize your `frequency` array to zeroes.

Comment: `int frequency[NUM_ALPHABETS] = {0};` (in fact it is a good idea to initialize all variables when you are learning C....) [C11 Standard - J.2 Undefined Behavior](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.2) "The value of an object with automatic storage duration is used while it is indeterminate (6.2.4, 6.7.9, 6.8)."

Comment: David and Christian, that did it! thanks so much. I'll remember to always initialize variables from now on lol

Comment: Long lines like that are almost impossible to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you relying on the frequency[] array to be initialized to 0s?

Also you can write step 2 as:

```
for(i = 0; sentence[i] != "\n"; i++) {
        if (isalpha(sentence[i]) {
                int index = tolower(sentence[i]) - 'a';
                frequency[index ]++;
        }
}
```

p.s.  Watch your single vs double quotes:

```
for(i = 0; sentence[i] != "\n"; i++)
```

Those should be single quotes around the '\n' to denote a character.

As others have pointed out, you need to initialize `frequency`. There are three ways to do that: provide an initializer, write a loop that sets each element to zero, or call `memset()`. This code does all three:

```
int frequency[26] = { 0 };
for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    frequency[i] = 0;
memset(frequency, 0, sizeof(frequency));
```

Note that `frequency` is misnamed since it actually contains the number of occurrences of each letter, not their frequency. To get the frequency, you'd have to divide by the total number of characters read. `MAXROWS` is also misnamed, since “row” is synonymous with “line”; you probably want to call it `MAXSENTENCELEN` or something similar instead.

Last but not least, `alphabets` is also misnamed since it only contains *one* alphabet, but you don't actually need it at all. Just check if the character is a letter, and if it is, use the difference between it and either `'A'` or `'a'` as an index into `frequency`. For bonus points, figure out a way to avoid the check and the subtraction... (hint: the numeric value of an upper-case letter and the corresponding lower-case letter in ASCII differ by only one bit)